# jquery/css - stack images, bring to front/back on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a way to have a few images, stacked on each other, with the image "behind" coming to the front on mouseover, with the image in "front" going to the back. The top image will be 100% size, with each image underneath being, say, 10% smaller and offset to the side, so there is an area to select it.

Something like this fiddle, except when the images begind are clicked, they are animated and brought to the front.

Is this possible, or are there any existing plugins that already provide this?

Comment: Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/833/

Comment: include all relevant code to OP. for demo use `<>` of SO

Answer (score 0):

You dont need JS for that, just add this to your current css.

```
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  1sition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Safari 3.1-6.0 */
  transition: width 1s, height 1s; 
}

#box1:hover,
#box2:hover,
#box3:hover,
#box4:hover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```